# ReferenceError on document event handling on ReactJS server side render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I'm working on a React.js app that must provide keyboard navigation on a horizontal scrolling carousel of items. On the current version, only left and right arrows are used to navigation and enter to make the selection. I'm mounting the listener on my container as:

```
const App = React.createClass({

  componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.__onKeyDown);
  },

  __onKeyDown(event){
     ...
  },

  render: function() {
     const items = []
     Array(10).fill().map((_, i) => items.push(<MovieItem />
     return (
        <div className="scroller">
          {items}
        </div>
     )
  }
});
```

The above code works as expected until I tried to make it server side. I added the following route on my server config file and got: **ReferenceError document is not defined**

```
import { Server } from 'http';
import express from 'express';
import routes from '../routes';

var app = express();

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    match(
        { routes, location: req.url },
        (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {

            let markup;
            if (renderProps) {
                markup = renderToString(
                    <Provider store={store}>
                        <RouterContext {...renderProps}/>
                    </Provider>
                );
            }
            return res.render('index', { markup });
        }
    );
});
```

It is clear to me why the error is happening, and that document is not available on the server. But what is the proper way to deal with it?

I have already tried to add a tabindex to the div that wraps the carousel and listen to div's onkeydown, but it just works when the div is focused.

Comment: Instead of adding event listener in `componentWillMount`, Use `componentDidMount` which executes only on client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding event listener in `componentWillMount`, Use `componentDidMount` which executes only on client.

[componentDidMount](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)